# How to get parameters name and value from url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

```
  function getURLParameter(url, name) {
        return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url)||[,null])[1];
  }
```

This function returns parameter's value receives url and parameter's name.

I want to change this function returns parameter's all name and value receives url.

How can I modify?

Comment: try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

```js
function getURLParams(url) {
  return Object.fromEntries(new URL(url).searchParams.entries());
}

var params = getURLParams('https://www.google.com/search?q=query+string&oq=query+string&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.10413j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8');
console.log(params);
console.log(params['ie']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

the to get your required value use

```
getUrlVars()["YourParameterInQueryString"]
```